# Console says variable is not nil, in tests it's nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

Have simple test:

```
  context "in the same board" do
    @link = FactoryGirl.create(:link_with_board, url: "www.onet.pl")
    @board = @link.board
    it "is invalid when the same url already exists" do
      expect(@board.links.build(url: "www.onet.pl")).to_not be_valid
      expect(@board.links.build(url: "http://www.onet.pl")).to_not be_valid
      expect(@board.links.build(url: "www.onet.pl/")).to_not be_valid
    end
  end
```

It shows me error:

```
Failures:

  1) Link in the same board is invalid when the same url already exists
     Failure/Error: expect(@board.links.build(url: "www.onet.pl")).to_not be_valid
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `links' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/models/link_spec.rb:50:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

When I try the same in console, it all works fine. Any idea why?

Update:

Ok, I made it work, but still question remains the same, why the first one didn't work?

```
  context "in the same board" do
    #FIX START
    before :each do
      @link = FactoryGirl.create(:link_with_board, url: "www.onet.pl")
      @board = @link.board
    end
    #FIX END
    it "is invalid when the same url already exists" do
      expect(@board.links.build(url: "www.onet.pl")).to_not be_valid
      expect(@board.links.build(url: "http://www.onet.pl")).to_not be_valid
      expect(@board.links.build(url: "www.onet.pl/")).to_not be_valid
    end
  end
```

Comment: Use `let` instead of instance variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting up `@link` and `@board` in a `context` block. This is a different scope to the `it` block, so when the `it` block runs those variables aren't defined.

Behind the scenes, `context` creates a class and `it` creates a method, so what you were doing was something similar to this:

```
class MyExampleGroup
  @link = FactoryGirl.create(:link_with_board, url: "www.onet.pl")
  @board = @link.board

  def it_is_invalid_sometimes
    @board.nil? # => true
  end
end
```

An instance variable set in class scope is visible in the class, but not in instances of the class.

When you moved them to before, the generated structure was more like this:

```
class MyExampleGroup
  def before
    @link = FactoryGirl.create(:link_with_board, url: "www.onet.pl")
    @board = @link.board
  end

  def it_is_invalid_sometimes
    @board.nil? # => false
  end
end
```

Now the instance variables are being defined in instance scope, so they work as you expect.

(I'm simplifying slightly for clarity: The methods created by `it` calls actually return `RSpec::Core::Example` objects, and the `before` blocks are run on those objects using `instance_exec`.)

Answer (score 1):

If you start the console with a simple `rails console` command, it connects to the development database (in a normal setup). But the tests are run against the test database.

In your test, the line creating the `@link`:

```rb
@link = FactoryGirl.create(:link_with_board, url: "www.onet.pl")
```

You might want to check how the `:link_with_board` factory is defined. (Probably in `spec/factories/*.rb`.)

Comment: `RAILS_ENV=test rails console` can switch to the test database, though usually the test database is empty because tests are run inside a transaction.

Comment: -1: The RAILS_ENV isn't the problem here, it's an ivar scope problem.

Comment: @Domon: I've made the same scoping mistake *so* many times it was easy for me to recognise :P